# slick carousel with lightbox to show div with background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add slick lightbox to slide, where is only div with background image. When open lightbox don't show image. What do you think? It is possible?

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
$('.slider-for').slickLightbox({
  src: false,
  itemSelector: '.team'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-for">
  <div class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background- repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </div>
  <div class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </div>
  <div class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </div>
  <div class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lighboxes to work with Slick while using CSS backgrounds, you need to use an `<a>` tag with an `href` that points to the image instead of `<div>` tags.

You should also avoid inline styles and use an external CSS sheet if possible.

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
$('.slider-for').slickLightbox({
  itemSelector: '.team'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-for">
  <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/700x350" class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </a>
  <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/700x350" class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </a>
  <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/700x350" class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </a>
  <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/700x350" class="team" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700x350); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:100%; background-size:cover; height: 350px; width:750px;">
  </a>
</div>
```